# Can't see updated HTML input value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If I click the "Show Value" button, it copies the text field value 0.75 to a result label.

But if I change the text field value to something else and click "Show Value", I still get 0.75.

Why is it that the `input` element's `value` attribute doesn't change based on the value of the input box?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var form = document.getElementById('theform');
   var edit = form.querySelector("input.parameter");
   var btn = form.querySelector("input.showit");
   var result = document.getElementById("result");
   var n = 0;
   btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     ++n;
     result.textContent = "Result: "+edit.getAttribute("value")+" (click #"+n+")";
   });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

<form id="theform">
  <label for="R">R</label>
  <input type="number" class="parameter" name="R" value="0.75">
  <input type="button" class="showit" value="Show Value">
  <label id="result">Result: </label>
</form>
</div>
```

(It's not just Javascript; if I look at the page in Chrome and open an Inspect window, the element's `value` never changes from 0.75.)

Comment: Try `edit.value` instead of reading the attribute with `edit.getAttribute("value")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually updating the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/value) property of the DOM element and not the `value` attribute. To make it works use [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/value) property of the DOM element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var form = document.getElementById('theform');
  var edit = form.querySelector("input.parameter");
  var btn = form.querySelector("input.showit");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var n = 0;
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    ++n;
    result.textContent = "Result: " + edit.value + " (click #" + n + ")";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <form id="theform">
    <label for="R">R</label>
    <input type="number" class="parameter" name="R" value="0.75">
    <input type="button" class="showit" value="Show Value">
    <label id="result">Result: </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, so the `value` property is the current value whereas `value` is just the initial value?

Comment: @JasonS :  yes, when you reset the form then it will revert back to the attribute value

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `edit.value` not `edit.getAttribute('value')`.

`edit.getAttribute('value')` is getting the attribute value and not the current value since modifying the input doesn't actually update the default attribute's value.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var form = document.getElementById('theform');
   var edit = form.querySelector("input.parameter");
   var btn = form.querySelector("input.showit");
   var result = document.getElementById("result");
   var n = 0;
   btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     ++n;
     result.textContent = "Result: "+edit.value+" (click #"+n+")";
   });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

<form id="theform">
  <label for="R">R</label>
  <input type="number" class="parameter" name="R" value="0.75">
  <input type="button" class="showit" value="Show Value">
  <label id="result">Result: </label>
</form>
</div>
```